# Remove shadows from Metacity windows

Tags: gnome, metacity, mutter

My goal is to remove the dropshadow from all metacity windows. I realize there is not a setting to do this and I may need to recompile metacity.

If I can simply do it by editing source files without compiling, an ideas where I can start on that?

Comment: Are you positive that there is no setting for that? Would you care to provide a source? It's quite believable, though, as just today I have read a quote from some Gnome-person that adding more options "has a price". Are you sure that the option is just not made available to you, but still is there? E.g. with tools such as `dconf-editor` et cetera ... ?

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/a/78376/15909

Comment: Here's a question I asked in Nov 2011 - http://askubuntu.com/a/78376/15909 I've actually been looking for a way to modify shadows this since then. That is, without compiz, xcompmgr, etc. I see no setting for shadows in dconf-editor or gconf-editor